# how do you create a context free grammar for this language and pda?

Tags: pushdown-automaton

Show that a set L containing equal number of 01s and 10s is regular ; 
[hint: L = {‘’, 0,00..,1,11…,010,101,…}, consider two branches; one starting with 0 and other with 1.]
Write a CFG and PDA for L.

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: copy and pasting exercises text is baaaaaad.